# Given an array of ints, return true if the sequence of numbers 1, 2, 3 appears in the array somewhere

Tags: java, arrays, netbeans, boolean

Basically i'm trying to return true, if 1, 2, 3 in that specific order are in the array, i cant work out how to do that though.

Ive already tried using some for loops and if statements but i dont know if that actually is the best way to do it

```
public static boolean arrayOneTwoThree(int[] nums) {
    for(int i = 0; i < nums.length - 2; i++) {
       if(nums[i] == 1 && nums[i + 1] == 2 && nums[i + i] == 3){
           return true;
       }
   }
   return false;
}
```

it only returns true if 1s 2s and 3s are in the array i want it to only return true if 1,2,3 are in they specific order[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SzfFK.png)

Comment: Consider using only one loop with end condition `i < nums.length-2`. In the loop, check the values of `nums[i] `, `nums[i+1] ` and `nums[i+2] ` .

Comment: This literally returns `true` for every single array, you do not do anything with `result`.  Please post the actual code you used, this is not the same code.

Comment: This equals `public boolean arrayOneTwoThree(int[] nums){ return true; }`

Answer (score 2):

```
public boolean arrayOneTwoThree(int[] nums) {

    // variables declaration.
    boolean result = false;
    int counter = 0,index = 0;
    int arr[] = {1,2,3};

     // base condition check. like array length should not be less than 3.
    if(nums.length < 3){
         return result;
    }

    //for loop for iterating over array and finding desired pattern
    for(int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++){

        //pattern found in array
        if(counter == 3){
          result = true;
          return result;
        }

        if(nums[i] == arr[counter]){
             index++; 
             counter++;
        }
        else if(counter != 0){
             i = index-1;
             counter = 0;
        }
    }     
    if (counter == 3) {
        result = true;
        return result;
    }  
    return result;
}
```

Complexity of this solution is O(n).

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few things wrong with you current code.

- You return `true` for every single case.
- You create a `result` variable and never do anything with it.
- You create three loops when you can use just a single one.
- You never actually check to see if the values are next to each other.

For the first problem, we will `return true` *only* when the `1, 2, 3` are next to each other, and `return false;` for EVERY other case.  This is done by using `return false;` after the loop.

For the next problem, `result` is not needed, you do not actually need to count anything, so remove this.

For the third issue, combine all the loops into a single loop.  However, we will need to loop to the condition of `nums.length - 2` instead of the `length` because we will comparing 3 values at the same time, and we do not want to get an `ArrayOutOfBoundsException`.

Finally, to check to see if all the values are next to each other, simply compare the values at the current Array index, the next one, and the index two values over with 1, 2 and 3 respectively.

This would look like `if (nums[i] == 1 && nums[i + 1] == 2 && nums[i + 2] == 3)`.  If this condition is `true`, we will `return true` immediately.

Here is how the code will look with all these fixes:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // test cases
    int [] arr = {1, 1 ,2, 1, 2, 3};
    System.out.println(arrayOneTwoThree(arr));

    int [] arr2 = {3, 2, 3};
    System.out.println(arrayOneTwoThree(arr2));
}

public static boolean arrayOneTwoThree(int[] nums) {
    for(int i = 0; i < nums.length - 2; i++) {
       if(nums[i] == 1 && nums[i + 1] == 2 && nums[i + 2] == 3){
           return true;
       }
   }
   return false;
}
```

**Test Runs:**

> true
>
> false

**Note:**  Remove `static` from the `arrayOneTwoThree(int [] nums)` if you need to use it in `non-static` context, I used `static` to test it from my `main`.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this solution and you may able to solve all your test cases

```
public static boolean find123(List<Integer> numbers) {

boolean isOneExist=false;
boolean isTwoExist=false;
boolean isThreeExist=false;
                        for(Integer n1:numbers)
            {
                    if(n1==1)
                {
                        isOneExist=true;
                }
                if(n1==2 && isOneExist)
                {
                    isTwoExist=true;
                }
                if(n1==3 && isTwoExist)
                {
                    isThreeExist=true;
                }
            
            }
            
            if(isOneExist && isTwoExist && isThreeExist)
            {
            return true;
            }
            
        return false;
    }
```